# Dygraphs locking on setSelection() isn't working

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I am having problems with locking on setSelection(). The correct value is being selected no problem, but the graph is not being locked afterward.

I have tried:

```
graph = new Dygraph(satgraph, data, { labels: [ "Score", "Percentage of people at this score"] });
.
.
.
graph.setSelection(intoStepSpace, { locked: [true] });
graph.setSelection(intoStepSpace, "", true); 
graph.setSelection(intoStepSpace, null, true);
graph.setSelection(intoStepSpace, undefined, true);

and, just in case they want a highlightSeriesOpts instead of the name of a series:

graph.setSelection(intoStepSpace, { highlightSeriesOpts: [
   {strokeWidth: 3},
   {strokeBorderWidth: 1},
   {highlightCircleSize: 5}]
 }, true);}
```

These were all tried individually, not sequentially like the above code shows.

Likely, this is a problem with my not understanding optional parameters in JavaScript well enough, but after reading about this concept I think I have it right. Is it obvious to anyone what I am doing wrong? It's been a long time since I've used JavaScript for anything, and I'm happy to be using Dygraphs to get back into it.

Thank you very much for the help.

-Brian J. Stinar-

Answer (score 1):

My super awesome programmer friend Jeremy Pepper mentioned two things to me:

1.) Locking appears to lock the selection to a specific series, not locking the entire graph.

2.)

```
graph.mouseMove_ = doNothing;
function doNothing()
{
}
```

Works. I don't know why this solution makes me feel dirty...